# How to change array elements that are greater than 5 to 5, in one line?

Tags: indexing, julia

I would like to take an array `x` and change all numbers greater than 5 to 5. What is the standard way to do this in one line?

Below is some code that does this in several lines. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189128/logical-indexing-in-julia) on logical indexing is related but appears to concern selection rather than assignment.
Thanks

```
x = [1 2 6 7]
for i in 1:length(x)
    if x[i] >= 5 
        x[i] = 5
    end
end
```

Desired output:
`x = [1 2 5 5]`

Comment: Note that in Julia, even though there are answers to this, you don't need them for performance. Loops are fast.

Comment: Too short for an answer, but this works: `clamp!(x, -Inf, 5)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The broadcast operator `.` works with any function, including relational operators, and it also works with assignment. Hence an intuitive one-liner is:

```
x[x .> 5] .= 5
```

This part `x .> 5` broadcasts `> 5` over `x`, resulting in a vector of booleans indicating elements greater than 5. This part `.= 5` broadcasts the assignment of `5` across all elements indicated by `x[x .> 5]`.

However, inspired by the *significant* speed-up in Benoit's very cool answer below (please do check it out) I decided to also add an optimized variant with a speed test. The above approach, while very intuitive looking, is not optimal because it allocates a temporary array of booleans for the indices. A (more) optimal approach that avoids temporary allocation, and as a bonus will work for any predicate (conditional) function is:

```
function f_cond!(x::Vector{Int}, f::Function, val::Int)
    @inbounds for n in eachindex(x)
        f(x[n]) && (x[n] = val)
    end
    return x
end
```

So using this function we would write `f_cond!(x, a->a>5, 5)` which assigns `5` to any element for which the conditional (anonymous) function `a->a>5` evaluates to `true`. Obviously this solution is not a neat one-liner, but check out the following speed tests:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x1 = rand(1:10, 100);

julia> x2 = copy(x1);

julia> @btime $x1[$x1 .> 5] .= 5;
  327.862 ns (8 allocations: 336 bytes)

julia> @btime f_cond!($x2, a->a>5, 5);
  15.067 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

This is just ludicrously faster. Also, you can just replace `Int` with `T<:Any`. Given the speed-up, one might wonder if there is a function in `Base` that already does this. A one-liner is:

```
map!(a->a>5 ? 5 : a, x, x)
```

and while this significantly speeds up over the first approach, it falls well short of the second.

Incidentally, I felt certain this must be a duplicate to another StackOverflow question, but 5 minutes searching didn't reveal anything.

Answer (score 7):

You can broadcast `min` as well:

```
x .= min.(x, 5)
```

Note that this is (slightly) more efficient than using `x[x .> 5] .= 5` because it does not allocate the temporary array of Booleans, `x .> 5`, and it can be automatically vectorized, with a single pass over the memory (as per Oscar's comment below):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = [1 2 6 7] ; @btime $x .= min.($x, 5) ; # fast, no allocations
  19.144 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> x = [1 2 6 7] ; @btime $x[$x .> 5] .= 5 ; # slower, allocates
  148.678 ns (5 allocations: 304 bytes)
```

Comment: This answer is almost certainly the faster answer

Comment: The other reason for the faster speed is that this solution can be automatically vectorized, and only makes one pass over the memory.

Comment: Nice tip! Adding that to the answer :)

Comment: To be complete, I have 15.608ns with the first approach, 175.689 with the second one and 12.215ns (0 allocations) with the for loop embedded in a function, so yes, loops are fast :-)

Comment: Oh this is *very* neat! Upvoted. But don't you mean `min`, not `max`? BTW given the significant increase in performance demonstrated in this answer I decided to edit mine to include the general case

Comment: You can also write `clamp!(x, -Inf, 5)`. I don't think it's quicker, but it might be easier to read -- more obviously an upper bound. Apparently I'm not the only one who has to read `min` vs. `max` twice to check which way around things should be.

Comment: Ha! of course! it should be `min`. Will edit accordingly. EDIT: Actually someone had suggested it already. Thanks!