# Logical/Boolean indexing of an array in Julia

Tags: indexing, julia

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5]
```

I want to replace entries 4 and 5( > 3) with 10.

I tried `a > 3`. Did not work out.

How to do this in Julia?

Related qn: [Logical Indexing in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189128/logical-indexing-in-julia)

Comment: Perhaps you have a good reason, but in case it's an oversight: You should probably use a vector `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` instead of a matrix `[1 2 3 4 5]`. They are similar, but also different in some critical ways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
julia> a = [1 2 3 4 5]
1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  4  5

julia> a[a .> 3] .= 10
2-element view(::Vector{Int64}, [4, 5]) with eltype Int64:
 10
 10

julia> a
1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  10  10
```

or

```
julia> a
1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  4  5

julia> replace(x -> x > 3 ? 10 : x, a) # allocates a new array
1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  10  10

julia> a # a is unchanged
1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  4  5

julia> replace!(x -> x > 3 ? 10 : x, a) # updates the array in place
1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  10  10

julia> a # a is updated in place
1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3  10  10
```

If you need to do this operation many times on large a array (e.g. inside a hot loop in some function that you call many times) then using `replace!` will be a faster option.